# How to check version of WTP in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

How can I check which version of WTP (Web Tools Platform) I am using in Eclipse?

I click on *Help --> About Eclipse* to open the About Eclipse window, then click on WTP icon to open this window:

[image]

But now how can I figure out the version of WTP I am using from the above window?

Thanks for reading the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the version can be located in the row where the "Feature Name" is "Eclipse Web Developer Tools"

See screen capture:
[image: eclipse]